# How to change Facebook password without SIM?

Tags: facebook

I created my Facebook account using my 'phone number, with an Airtel SIM.

It was locked, how do I open it?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you must have any recovery email which was filled by you at the time of registration on Facebook.
You can't recover your password without any recovery medium(phone number/ recovery email). This is must needed for verifying the valid user.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Facebook account from a computer and change the password. Or connect your mobile with WiFi, login the Facebook and change the password. Or use a different sim, connect internet (use mobile data in case you don't have WiFi), login Facebook to change the password.

Another method is use someone else phone, login your Facebook account and change the password.